# iOS - corebluetooth retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices: - how to get Advertisement Data?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ads

I'm writing a suite of Bluetooth Low-Energy app for iOS 7.
When the app launches, there's a fair chance the peripheral I'm interested in is still connected to the iOS device, and to avoid scanning for the peripheral it would be great to connect immediately.  `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:` looks perfect for this, and indeed seems to work as advertised: I get a list of CBPeripherals which are connected to the device via some backgrounded app.

So far so good, but here's the issue:

There's information in the AdvertisementData which I want, but I don't know how to get the AdvertisementData when going this route.
[As far as I can see](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html), advertisementData is only available as a result of scanning.

So my question is this:
* Given a `CBPeripheral` returned by `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:`, how can I get the associated `advertisementData` for that peripheral ?

One workaround would take advantage of the fact that the device was likely connected to another of the apps in my own suite, so I could persist the advertisement data myself in storage shared between the apps, but this is neither clean nor ideal, because there's a chance the device was connected to someone else's app, and so I'd have no insight into the advertisement data in that scenario, and would need to resort to a scan.

Comment: Many— but not all— peripherals will offer the same services advertised via their GATT. This comment may or may not be helpful, depending on what you want to do and what peripherals you want to talk to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the advertisement data is available only if you scan. It is not possible to retrieve it from Core Bluetooth or any other framework in any other way. You should revise your design if the advertisement is so important and rather go along the scanning route.